# Rotate element by e.target.style in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, rotation

I am trying to rotate element after changing phone to show. F.e when clicking Iphone 12 Pro Max (PhoneBox) then will show box with details about it and I want to rotate this box (DescDetails). I was trying to do this in function rotateBox by gettind e.target.style but event is undefined although the function is working (i see it by console.log(hello)). So my question why event is undefinded and how can I fix that?

Lint to stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-epnmz9?file=src/App.js

Code:

```
function PhonesSection() {
  const [showPhoneSeries, setShowPhoneSeries] = useState("Apple");
  const [activePhoneSeries, setActivePhoneSeries] = useState("");
  const [showPhoneModel, setShowPhoneModel] = useState();

  const handleShowPhoneSeries = e => {
    let seriesName = e.target.textContent;
    setShowPhoneSeries(seriesName);

  };
  const rotateBox = e => {
    console.log("hello");
    console.log(e);
    // e.target.className.add('rotate');
    // e.target.style.transform = 'rotateY(360deg)';
    // e.target.style.transition = 'all 0.3s ease-in';
  };

  const handleShowPhoneModel = model => {
    setShowPhoneModel(model);
    //rotateBox(model)
  };

  const showBoxes = phones
    .filter(phone => phone.series === showPhoneSeries)
    .map((phone, index) => (
      <PhoneBox key={index} onClick={() => handleShowPhoneModel(phone.model)}>
        <PhoneImage src={phone.img} />

        <PhoneName>{phone.model}</PhoneName>
      </PhoneBox>
    ));

  const showPhoneModelBox = phones
    .filter(phone => phone.model === showPhoneModel)
    .map((phone, index) => (
      <>
        <DescImage src={phone.img} />
        <DescDetails onClick={rotateBox()}>
          <DescPhoneName>{phone.model}</DescPhoneName>
          <Table>
            <Tr>
              <Td>RAM:</Td>
              <Td>{phone.ram}</Td>
            </Tr>

            <Tr>
              <Td>Storage:</Td>
              <Td>{phone.storage}</Td>
            </Tr>
            <Tr>
              <Td>Camera:</Td>
              <Td>{phone.camera}</Td>
            </Tr>
            <Tr>
              <Td>Size:</Td>
              <Td>{phone.size}</Td>
            </Tr>
            <Tr>
              <Td>Battery:</Td>
              <Td>{phone.battery}</Td>
            </Tr>
            <Tr>
              <Td>Price:</Td>
              <Td>{phone.price}</Td>
            </Tr>
          </Table>
          <Button>Go to store</Button>
        </DescDetails>
      </>
    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question why event is undefinded and how can I fix that?

because of

`<DescDetails onClick={rotateBox()}>`

this will assign the returned value of `rotateBox`(which is undefined because the function isn't returning anything) to `onClick`. So the fix should be as simple as

`<DescDetails onClick={rotateBox}>`

Comment: Aww what an obvious mistake.. I event didn't see it. Thanks !